# how to clear value in getxcontroller in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-getx

how can I clear value in get x controller?
for now I need to restart my app every time I need to input different value.

my text controller class :

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class TextControllers extends GetxController {
  Rx<TextEditingController> usernameController = TextEditingController().obs;
  Rx<TextEditingController> passwordController = TextEditingController().obs;
  Rx<TextEditingController> vendor1Controller = TextEditingController().obs;
  Rx<TextEditingController> stocktableController = TextEditingController().obs;
  Rx<TextEditingController> fixassetController = TextEditingController().obs;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use clear function

```
  clearTextInput(){
    usernameController.clear();
    passwordController.clear();
    vendor1Controller.clear();
    stocktableController.clear();
    fixassetController.clear();
  }
```

Comment: hello, where i put this code?

Comment: just call the function clearTextInput where you want to clear the values

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for clearing TextEditingController value.

Paste this inside you `TextControllers` class.

```
  @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    usernameController.value.clear();
    passwordController.value.clear();
    vendor1Controller.value.clear();
    stocktableController.value.clear();
    fixassetController.value.clear();
  }
```

Comment: hello, thankyou for answering, but still didn't work